# Add duplicate shortcut key issue

Tags: 20.04, shortcut-keys, xdotool

I want to add a duplicate shortcut key for `"Home"` and for this I have tried different commands but none of them are working.
I want that my custom key should move cursor to the start like when we press the `Home` key.
So in `Keyboard shortcuts` I am trying below commands against my new shortcut key `Ctrl+Left`.

```
xdotool key Home
xdotool key --clearmodifiers Home
/bin/bash -c "sleep 1 && xdotool key Home"
```

The last command only works after the delay of 1 sec that is not good as we want instant cursor move. I tried to make sleep 0 but does not work.

Comment: shorter sleep  sleep 0.005    - see https://linuxhandbook.com/bash-sleep/

Comment: no it's not working in points.

Answer (score 2):

Use `keyup` to have xdotool "release" your custom hotkey before simulating hitting the <kbd>Home</kbd> key, as in:

```
xdotool keyup ctrl+Left key Home
```

Without the "keyup", your custom shortcut key may/will still be in effect while xdotool is hitting <kbd>Home</kbd>.

Comment: This is working fine but I'm facing an issue that I need to release the `Ctrl` key if I want to move right and left multiple times.